# ** operator behaving differently

Tags: python, python-3.x

if I execute following in IDLE:

```
-1**2
```

it returns -1. However, executing the same through a function returns positive value

```
def star(x):
    return x**2
star(-1)
```

returns 1

Why is the same operation behaving differently in IDLE when executed directly or through function?

Comment: The expression `-(1**2)` is not the same thing as `(-1)**2`.

Comment: Interesting..  The issue was that while I'm not using parentheses in either option, but direct execution in IDLE takes it as -1**2 where as same thing through function works as (-1)**2   which means parameter wraps () before executing ** in function..

Comment: Assigning `-1` to a variable, then executing `x ** 2` is the same as `(-1) ** 2`, as you are applying the exponent to the result of the `-1` expression (unary minus applied to 1). It's the same as using `sum = 2 + 4`, then `print(sum * 3)` versus `print(2 + 4 * 3)`; you force a different precedence by placing parentheses or by calculating separately.